# How to add delay of 10 sec to my ajax call on below code

Tags: ajax

How to add delay of 10 sec to my ajax call on below code

```
 new Ajax.Request(url, {
                        method: 'Post',
                        parameters: {"status": "test"},
                        onComplete: function (transport) {
                            transport.responseText;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: `window.setTimeout`

Comment: can you please explain with my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.setTimeout(function(){
  new Ajax.Request(url, {
      method: 'Post',
      parameters: {"status": "test"},
      onComplete: function (transport) {
          transport.responseText;
      }
  });
}, 10000)
```